# Laravel Carbon getting trailing data error

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5, php-carbon

Error when Using Laravel eloquent model, my database timestamp field has 2018-02-09 12:55:06.1234 while using Carbon on this I get trailing data error as below in json. How to fix it.

```
{
"draw": 1,
"recordsTotal": 641,
"recordsFiltered": 0,
"data": [],
"error": "Exception Message:\n\nTrailing data"
}
```

Comment: I dont see a few things here. a) Code, b) A real question and c) the error you are speaking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just have to truncate seconds in `created_at` field. Its working for me:

```
update mrlpay.terminals set created_at=date_trunc('seconds', created_at);
```

Comment: now i am using this for temporary. But i Need correct solution. Thanks